# Flutter stripe_payment (no such intent)

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments

I'm trying to use stripe_payment package so, I copied the example, pasted it in a new project, and changed the publishable key with my own test one and the client secret with as well, but when I try to (Confirm Payment Intent) this error appears

```
W/System.err(16083): com.stripe.android.exception.InvalidRequestException: No such payment_intent: 'sk_test_51HeoJlKcQzB5OdSOt6U9dHeE0AycFD0go3mogovD0SDtBWNIxesy5p5R414Z8dPiIDkPS88ecWhtIKqibOiyW9XA00em5I6n1c'; request-id: req_orAO8CijdAtOrI
W/System.err(16083):    at com.stripe.android.StripeApiRepository.handleAPIError(StripeApiRepository.kt:784)
W/System.err(16083):    at com.stripe.android.StripeApiRepository.makeApiRequest(StripeApiRepository.kt:828)
W/System.err(16083):    at com.stripe.android.StripeApiRepository.confirmPaymentIntent(StripeApiRepository.kt:78)
W/System.err(16083):    at com.stripe.android.PaymentController$ConfirmStripeIntentTask.getResult$stripe_release(PaymentController.kt:355)
W/System.err(16083):    at com.stripe.android.PaymentController$ConfirmStripeIntentTask.getResult(PaymentController.kt:343)
W/System.err(16083):    at com.stripe.android.ApiOperation.doInBackground(ApiOperation.java:22)
W/System.err(16083):    at com.stripe.android.ApiOperation.doInBackground(ApiOperation.java:11)
W/System.err(16083):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:378)
W/System.err(16083):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
W/System.err(16083):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:289)
W/System.err(16083):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
W/System.err(16083):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
W/System.err(16083):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

What the cause of this error?, thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add your code? 
Based on the error it looks like you've set `client_secret` to your Stripe secret test API key (which you should now roll). It should be set to the `client_secret` of the PaymentIntent you're trying to confirm (https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object#payment_intent_object-client_secret) and should be of the form pi_xxx_secret_xxx

Comment: Yes, I replaced the client secret with my Stripe secret, but based on this example, how can I get the correct client_secret?
https://pub.dev/packages/stripe_payment/example

Comment: You need to create a PaymentIntent yourself, either through your own server backend or through a curl command (https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create?lang=curl). It looks like others have had the same question https://github.com/jonasbark/flutter_stripe_payment/issues/85